# How can I create a command line (unix/linux) instruction that uses variables to execute numerous commands?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I need to rearrange some content in various directories but it's a bit of a pain. In order to debug the application I'm working on (a ruby app) I need to move my gems into my gem folder one at a time (long story; nutshell: one is broken and I can't figure out which one).

So I need to do something like:

```
sudo mv backup/gem/foo gem/
sudo mv backup/doc/foo doc/
sudo mv backup/specification/foo.gemspec specification/
```

replacing "foo" each time. How can I author a simple shell script to let me do something like: gemMove("foo") and it fill in the blanks for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following into a file named `gemmove`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "x$1" == x ]; then
  echo "Must have an arg"
  exit 1
fi

for d in gem doc specification ; do 
  mv "backup/$d/$1" "$d"
done
```

then do

```
chmod a+x gemmove
```

and then call `sudo /path/to/gemmove foo` to move the foo gem from the backup dirs into the real ones

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the bash shell arguments, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is move.sh
mv backup/gem/$1 gem/
mv backup/doc/$1 doc/
# ...
```

and then execute it as:

```
sudo ./move.sh foo
```

Be sure make the script executable, with

```
chmod +x move.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

in bash, something like:

```
function gemMove()
{
filename=$1
   mv backup/gem/$filename gem/$filename
   mv backup/doc/$filename doc/$filename
   mv backup/specification/$filename.spec specification
}
```

then you can just call `gemMove("foo")` elsewhere in the script.

Comment: Or you can add the function to your .bashrc to make it always available.